# How to correct the order of error bars on a barplot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bar plot of an association test conducted between a phenotype and several different costs.

As I am plotting each phenotype vs the different costs, I have added a position dodge to the ggplot code, however, when I add error bars they do not *always* seem to match the positions of the bars themselves. I know there are a few other questions which ask the same thing, but in those questions the answer always seems to be to get rid of the position dodge, and that would not be an ideal solution for me. Any help appreciated.

You can see my best attempt at creating this with the image below:

[image: My current attempt at the figure]

As you can see, the error bars actually for the most part seem to correspond to the appropriate bar, but then at some point (around "VTE") the order gets mixed up. It's not completely out of whack as it seems like the error bars are still being grouped by the "PRS" but they just aren't corresponding to the correct phenotype.

This uses the following code:

```
ggplot(input_frame, aes(x = beta, y = reorder(factor(score), beta), fill = factor(trait))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +  # Use position = "dodge" to group by PRS
  labs(x = "Beta", y = "PRS") +
  theme_linedraw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = legend_colours, name = "Phenotype", labels = legend_labels) +  # Set custom colors for phenotypes
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = beta - se, xmax = beta + se, y = reorder(factor(score), beta), color = signif),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                size = 0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"), name = "Significance") +
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"))
```

It's worth adding that removing the `y = reorder(factor(score), beta)` from the `aes` of the `geom_errorbar` does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Try to replace `geom_error_bar` with `stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", aes(color = signif), fun.data = "mean_se", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 0.2)`

Comment: The issue is most likely that the grouping used for geom_bar (grouping by `fill=factor(trait)`) is different to the one used by geom_errobar (grouping by `color = signif`). Try with `geom_errobar(aes(..., group=factor(trait)))`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: @WillOldham this didn't seem to actually produce anything at all (no errors or warnings, but no actual bars of any kind on the plot).

Comment: @stefan, your solution fixed it! Amazing, thank you!